# "SELECT ... IN (SELECT ...)" query in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT username 
FROM users 
WHERE locationid IN 
  (SELECT locationid FROM locations WHERE countryid='$')
```

$ is a value I get from end user.

How could I run this query in CodeIgniter? I can't find a solution in CodeIgnite's user guide.

Thank you so much for your answers!

Regards!

Comment: Just a note to say joins > subselects: `select username from users
inner join locations on
users.locationid = locations.locationid
where countryid = '$'`

Answer (score 7):

Look [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html).

Basically you have to do bind params:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE locationid IN (SELECT locationid FROM locations WHERE countryid=?)"; 

$this->db->query($sql, '__COUNTRY_NAME__');
```

But, like Mr.E said, use joins:

```
$sql = "select username from users inner join locations on users.locationid = locations.locationid where countryid = ?"; 

$this->db->query($sql, '__COUNTRY_NAME__');
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that these solutions use the [Code Igniter Active Records Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html)

This method uses sub queries like you wish but you should sanitize `$countryId` yourself!

```
$this->db->select('username')
         ->from('user')
         ->where('`locationId` in', '(select `locationId` from `locations` where `countryId` = '.$countryId.')', false)
         ->get();
```

Or this method would do it using joins and will sanitize the data for you (**recommended**)!

```
$this->db->select('username')
         ->from('users')
         ->join('locations', 'users.locationid = locations.locationid', 'inner')
         ->where('countryid', $countryId)
         ->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, to note - the [Active Record Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select) also has a `$this->db->where_in()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a simple SQL query:

```
$sql="select username from user where id in (select id from idtables)";
$query=$this->db->query($sql);
```

and then you can use it normally.