# How to write the given query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to write the given query in codeigniter , how can I do so?

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` IN (select `provider_id` from `services`);
```

I gone through codeigniter's where_in() but i'm getting wrong result , here what I have done,

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from(USER);
$this->db->where_in('id', 'select `provider_id` from `services`');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();
```

it is returning 0, while the query above, when run directly in phpmyadmin, returns 1 record.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315511/select-in-select-query-in-codeigniter

Comment: $this->db->query is easiest way if you cannot use CI active record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple way `$this->db->query('your query');`

Please check this post, hope it will help you [Using Mysql WHERE IN clause in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass direct queries in where class by passing second parameter as NULL and third parameter as FALSE

```
<?php 
$where = 'id IN (select `provider_id` from `services`)';
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from(USER);
$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: Hello thanks for helping, I tried all the 3(Suvash, Sundar, and Vinie) answers and all of them are working. Thanks for the alternate ways...

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->db->query();`

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id` IN (select `provider_id` from `services`)");
$num=$query->num_rows();
$result= $query->result();
```